# How to minify JS with Django templates, and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

Setup:

- Django, currently using Django-Compressor for CSS
- Nested Templates using Django templatetags to nest
- RequireJS to pull in JS modules.

Example:

base.html:

```
<html>
...
<script src="/static/js/libs/require.js">
...
{% include "body.html" %}
...
<script>
     require(['/static/js/base']);
</script>
</html>
```

body.html

```
<h1> This is the body </h1>
<script>
     require(['/static/js/body']);
</script>
```

So with this setup none of my JS files are being compressed. I can't use Django-Compressor because it won't utilize requireJS correctly, nor can I find anything that will help in this case.
Some ideas I have come up with have been to minify the JS files in place, or to run gulp/grunt beside Django, but that would make local development ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using django-pipeline?

https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

With it's template tag to pull in JS files, you may be able to replace both RequireJS and Django-Compressor.